# Is there a way to get keyof own type in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it somehow possible to get the values in columns as a type in valueFormatter datacolumn?
So if i were to input id, firstname and lastname as columns like shown below i would only get those as a type on valueformatter function?

Goal is go get the columns (id, firstname and lastname) as type on valueformatter

```
import "./App.css";

interface TableColumn {
  name: string;
  // TODO: make this type same as type of the keys in one of the objects in rows
  valueFormatter?: (datacolumn: {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
  }) => void;
}

interface TableProps {
  columns: TableColumn[];
  rows: any[];
}

const Table = ({ columns, rows }: TableProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {rows.map((row, index) => (
          <div key={`row-${index}`} style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
            {columns.map((col) => (
              <div
                key={col.name}
                style={{ padding: "1rem", border: "1px solid white" }}
              >
                {col.valueFormatter ? col.valueFormatter(row) : row[col.name]}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "id",
      valueFormatter: (row) => {
        return row.firstname + "some value";
      },
    },
    { name: "firstname" },
    { name: "lastname" },
  ];
  const rows = [{ id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" }];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} rows={rows} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sleepy-thunder-23vwdh?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A1%2C1-48%2C1

Comment: The question is not clear. Pasting your code in codesandbox gives error. Please edit this and link to the question https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/restless-framework-tsdn2f?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A20%2C1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is generics. Something like this would work for you.

```
// takes generic Row
type TableColumn<Row> = {
  name: keyof Row & string;
  valueFormatter?: (datacolumn: Row) => string;
};

// takes generic Row and passes it to TableColumn.
type TableProps<Row> = {
  columns: TableColumn<Row>[];
  rows: Row[];
};

// takes generic Row but this time it extends Record<string, any>
// instead of any, you can specify string | number etc...
// you can extend in the other generic Row implementations above too. 
// It would make sense if you did actually. But not necessary.
const Table = <Row extends Record<string, any>>({
  columns,
  rows,
}: TableProps<Row>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {rows.map((row, index) => (
          <div key={`row-${index}`} style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
            {columns.map((col) => (
              <div
                key={col.name}
                style={{ padding: "1rem", border: "1px solid white" }}
              >
                {col.valueFormatter ? col.valueFormatter(row) : row[col.name]}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {

  // define a Row that you will use
  type Row = {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
  };

  // use TableColumn<Row> type so that typescript holds your hand while writing the columns.
  const columns: TableColumn<Row>[] = [
    {
      name: "id",
      valueFormatter: (row) => {
        // you get nice editor support for row here.
        return row.firstname + "some value";
      },
    },
    { name: "firstname" },
    { name: "lastname" },
  ];

  // You can use Row[] here as well.
  const rows: Row[] = [{ id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" }];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} rows={rows} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This way, you can separate your Table component and use it with as many Row types as you wish. export TableColumn and TableProps so that you can use them in your components that will use the Table component.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot to you and tuomokar for helping me out :D

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the row object's type and valueFormatter function's type to their own type variables and then use those in both TableColumn and the actual implementation of valueFormatter.

```
type RowObject = {
  id: number;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

// Note that you have the return type for the value formatter marked as void
// but you return a string from it, so used that here.
type ValueFormatter = (rowObject: RowObject) => string;

interface TableColumn {
  name: string;
  valueFormatter?: ValueFormatter
}

// then in App.tsx:

// Type the variable itself here
const columns: TableColumn[] = [
  {
    name: "id",
    // No need to type the row here explicitly as the columns variable itself
    // is typed so TypeScript also knows the type of the row variable from that
    valueFormatter: (row) => {
      return row.firstname + "some value";
    },
  },
  { name: "firstname" },
  { name: "lastname" },
];

// Type also this variable for safety
const rows:: RowObject[] = [{ id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" }];
```

Then you can also type the `rows` prop in Table component properly.

Comment: that could work yeah, but say i would add another field to column/type to rowobject. could it be possible to basicly autogenerate RowObject type?

Comment: I don't see how that would be adding another field anywhere. You just specify the types. There are no extra fields.

Comment: yeah, but say i would add age to the object, 
`const rows = [{ id: 1, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 5 }];`

would it be possible to automatically add age to the RowObject type without having to do it manually?

Comment: Not if you want to use that age variable typesafely.
If you don't care about the type safety, you could of course type the row object with mapped types so that its keys are any strings (something like `RowObject = {[key: string]: unknown`; That works fine if you use the object dynamically (e.g. just render all the properties via Object.keys) but it doesn't really fit your valueFormatter if you want to render only some of the fields (though if it's always the same fields, then you could type those and type it so that the rest of the keys can be any strings).

Comment: yes, think declaring a seperate type is the best way to go then :) 
Thanks a lot for the help.